# what is the complimentary method of pd.DataFrame.drop()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is how I drop rows based on given `index_value`.

```
df_new = df.drop(df.index[index_value])
```

If I want to drop all the rows other than which is mentioned in `index_value` from dataframe `df`
How to do it?

Index value is `ind.ind1`

```
ind

     ind1  ind2
0       0     2
1       1     6
2       2     8
3       3     9
4       4    14
```

```
df
     index     YearDeci  Year  Month  ...    Lon  Depth  Magnitude  Mag_Type
0     6131  2018.023393  2018      1  ...  76.16      5        2.9        ML
1     6132  2018.114803  2018      2  ...  77.22     10        2.5        MW
2     6133  2018.137808  2018      2  ...  75.82     10        3.2        ML
3     6134  2018.159566  2018      2  ...  78.68     10        3.1        ML
4     6135  2018.186685  2018      3  ...  76.67     10        4.0        MW
```

Comment: `df.loc[index_value]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `index.difference`:

```
df_new = df.drop(df.index.difference([index_value]))
```

Comment: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example please?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with `~`:

```
df_new = df.drop(~df.index.isin([index_value]))
```

**OR:**

As @Ch3steR mentioned in the comment:

Just select the row with index you want:

```
df_new = df.loc[index_value]
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly drop the desired index from the dataframe

```
df.drop(ind.ind1.to_list())
```

Comment: TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable